# PHP gallery autogenerated thumb to open larger image in <div> on click

Tags: php, jquery, gallery, phpthumb

Sorry in advance if it's a stupid question, but I'm a complete newbie and this is the first bit of PHP I've ever looked at in my life.

I've taken the code [from this web post](http://www.daveismyname.com/tutorials/php-tutorials/creating-an-image-gallery-from-a-folder-of-images-automatically/) about **Creating an image gallery from a folder of images automatically** and it creates a gallery of thumbnails which, when clicked, open a larger image as a separate page.

**What I would like is for the thumbnails to open the larger image inside a 'div' on the same page.**

I've managed to achieve this by using 'iframe', but I'm aware that's a solution which is frowned upon:

```
<iframe id="r5-6c2-4" name="bigimg" src="" width="625px" height="410px" frameBorder="0">
</iframe> 

<div id="r5-6c1">
     <div id="thumbscontainer">
         <ul>
             <?php
                  $images = glob('g-images/*.jpg');
                  $ignore = array('cgi-bin', '.', '..','._');
                  foreach($images as $curimg){
                  if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
                  echo "<li><a href='".$dirname.$curimg."' target='bigimg'><img src='thumby.php?src=".$dirname.$curimg."&h=193&zc=0' alt='' /></a></li>\n ";
                   }
               }                 
               ?>                    
           </ul>
     </div>          
</div>
```

Help please! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a newbie too but I'd try this,

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {           
    $('body').append('<div><img id="moo" src=""></div>');
    $("a[target='bigimg']").on('click',function(a){
      a.preventDefault();
      $('img#moo').attr('src',$(this).attr('href'));
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: James, thank you so much, it works!!!! Instead of the 'iframe' i've created a "div" containing an "img" tag with the "id=r5-6c2-4" and added you're script and...voila'!!! I'M SERIOUSLY GRATEFUL :-)

Comment: If I may pose an additional question: how would you go about to **add captions/tooltips** similar to the ones that can be seen here [link](http://development.tobypitman.com/slideshow/index3.html#3) ?

Comment: Thanks :)

You could try adding titles (putting titles on your link like <a title="my caption") and:

`$('body').append('<div style="float:left;position:relative"><img id="moo" src=""><div id="caption" style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;width:100%;background:black;color:white;opacity:.6;"><p style="padding:10px;"></p></div></div>');

$("a[target='bigimg']").on('click',function(a){
  a.preventDefault();
  $('img#moo').attr('src',$(this).attr('href'));
  $('div#caption p').text($(this).attr('title'));
}); `

Comment: Hey James, thank you for the suggestion - though, I was looking for something like making am XML file containing all the captions that is going to be read when the thumbnail gallery is created from the folder, like is shown in the first bit of this tutorial [link](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/05/23/fresh-sliding-thumbnails-gallery-with-jquery-php/) - I just can't quite see how the php would be for my situation...oh, and MERRY XMAS!!! :-)